# Not able to understand coffee script

Tags: jquery

This line is present in my code

```
search.court_type_popover = new ObjectListPopover(
  $('#pacer-flyout .jurisdiction-selector'), 
  'Jurisdiction', data, true, false, 
   $('#pacer-flyout input[name=pacersites]').val().split('|'))
```

Can anybody explain me this code?
what will it return?
and how it will generate result?

Comment: This is not a coffeescript question but a jQuery/javascript question. The only thing I can see that is coffeescript-like about it is the lack of a semicolon at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty much plain ol' JavaScript aside from a missing semicolon at the end:

```
search.court_type_popover = new ObjectListPopover(...);
```

From what I can tell, this code assigns `search.court_type_popover` to be a new `ObjectListPopover` object and passes in some arguments.